# "$: command not found" Command error while reconfiguring keyboard configuration in Ubuntu 18.04.03 console

Tags: server, dpkg

I am getting error `$: command not found` while executing following command `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` for reconfiguring **keyboard configuration** in Ubuntu 18.04.03 console. Kindly assist what went wrong.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. We just have to remove `$` from the command `$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. So the correct command is `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Comment: A prefix of `$` usually means the command can be executed as a non-privileged user. A prefix of `#` may either mean that it requires a privileged user to execute it (e.g. `root`) or that it is intended as a comment.